# Could not find generator AddListingIdToOrders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to add an id to my orders database 
when i run the migration at the command line  $ rails generate AddListingIdToOrders listing_id:integer
it gives me an error Could not find generator AddListingIdToOrders.

cmd neilpatel$ rails generate AddListingIdToOrders listing_id:integer
Could not find generator AddListingIdToOrders.

listing.rb

```
class Listing < ActiveRecord::Base
    if Rails.env.development?
        has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "photo.jpg"
    else
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "200x", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "photo.jpg",
                      :storage => :dropbox,
                      :dropbox_credentials => Rails.root.join("config/dropbox.yml"),
                      :path => ":style/id_:filename"
    end
    validates :name, :description, :price, presence: true
    validates :price, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
    validates_attachment_presence :image

    belongs_to :user
    has_many  :orders
end
```

orders.rb

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :address, :city, :state, presence: true

```
belongs_to :listing
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're looking for is

```
rails generate migration AddListingIdToOrders listing_id:integer
```

You're missing the 'migration' part :)